# Error trying to diff ‘[object Object]'` needs to pass the error message

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

It works fine when I pass `[ngValue]="operator.value"`. When I change the `ngValue` to `"operator"`, the error changes to

> "trying to diff '[Object object]'"

I am trying to post complete array instead of value.

**HTML Code:**

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="operators" (change)="onChangeOfUdfParamValue(i,operators)">
 <option [ngValue]="opera" *ngFor="let opera of formula.controls.operators.value" [attr.selected]="opera.selected ? true : null" >
 {{opera.display}}
</option>
 </select>
```

**JSON format:**

```
"operators": [
                    {
                        "display": "=",
                        "value": ">",
                        "active": true,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "display": ">",
                        "value": ">",
                        "active": true,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "<",
                        "value": "<",
                        "active": true,
                        "selected": false
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: please recheck the spelling of [ngValue]="opera" @SVK

Comment: Your code shows `[ngValue]= "opera"`, but you say you are trying to send `[ngValue]="operator.value"` and `[ngValue]="operator"`

Comment: I am trying to post json format with selected key as true to that object. so Im passing [ngValue] as opera @AmitChigadani

Answer (score 0):

**Error Due to** :

> Array of object was converted to object

***Two ways to solve:***

**Solution 1:** `Change object to new formArray().`

**Solution 2:** `change formcontrolName to other name which will create new formcontrol().`